# Quotes in a string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good Day. I have an ajax function and return this:

```
<tr onClick="obtener_articulo('1960|X36-004|X36004|Cheque Horizontal de Bronce 200 WOG  de   1/4 " 125 Gramos|0||0|0|Unidad||0.000|0|0||noimage.png')"><td>X36-004</td><td>Cheque Horizontal de Bronce 200 WOG  de   1/4 " 125 Gramos</td></tr>
```

Using javascript i will add that value to a tabla (i can do that already). My problem is the character " beacuse javascript give this error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal. I need the character " in that value. I am getting that value from database.

I tried to replace " with \" but did not work.

Comment: If you're producing the string from another language, you may need to replace the `"` (or `\"`) with `\\"` so the escape isn't interpreted by the first language and actually ends up in the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to update the server code producing the string to produce valid HTML.

The content of `onclick` attributes (like all attributes) is **HTML** text. People tend to forget that. :-) So if the quotes around the `onclick` attribute value are `"`, use `&quot;` within the value for a `"`:

```
<tr onClick="obtener_articulo('1960|X36-004|X36004|Cheque Horizontal de Bronce 200 WOG  de   1/4 &quot; 125 Gramos|0||0|0|Unidad||0.000|0|0||noimage.png')"><td>X36-004</td><td>Cheque Horizontal de Bronce 200 WOG  de   1/4 &quot; 125 Gramos</td></tr>
```

It looks weird to see that in what looks like JavaScript code, but think about the layers involved: The parser reads the HTML, building up a string attribute value, interpreting entities along the way; then it passes that interpreted string to the JavaScript engine, which sees `"`.

Gratuitous live example:

```html
<div onclick="alert(&quot;Hi there&quot;);">Click me</div>
<div onclick="alert('1/2 &quot;');">And me</div>
```